# Proguard: AmazonAWS and MBean issue

Tags: proguard

I'm trying to shrink a Scala project with Proguard that requires the Amazon AWS libraries. The original JAR file works as expected but the shrunken one throws an exception that some classes don't implement MBean conventions. I sorted out several similar of these issues before using "-keep" options but this time I'm lost.

Any ideas how to solve it are appreciated?

```
Jul 02, 2016 9:29:38 AM com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport registerMetricAdminMBean
WARNING: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: MBean class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin does not implement DynamicMBean, and neither follows the Standard MBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin is not a JMX compliant Standard MBean) nor the MXBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin: Class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin is not a JMX compliant MXBean)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.registerMBean(MBeans.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.registerMetricAdminMBean(SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.registerMetricAdminMBean(AwsSdkMetrics.java:390)
    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.<clinit>(AwsSdkMetrics.java:351)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<clinit>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:245)
    at mycode.MinimalTest$.entry(MinimalTest.scala:275)
    at mycode.MinimalTest$.main(MinimalTest.scala:248)
    at mycode.MinimalTest.main(MinimalTest.scala)
Caused by: javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: MBean class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin does not implement DynamicMBean, and neither follows the Standard MBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin is not a JMX compliant Standard MBean) nor the MXBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin: Class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin is not a JMX compliant MXBean)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Introspector.checkCompliance(Introspector.java:176)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:317)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.registerMBean(MBeans.java:52)
    ... 7 more

Jul 02, 2016 9:29:38 AM com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport registerMetricAdminMBean
WARNING: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: MBean class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin does not implement DynamicMBean, and neither follows the Standard MBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin is not a JMX compliant Standard MBean) nor the MXBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin: Class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin is not a JMX compliant MXBean)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.registerMBean(MBeans.java:56)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.registerMetricAdminMBean(SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.java:27)
    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.registerMetricAdminMBean(AwsSdkMetrics.java:399)
    at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.<clinit>(AwsSdkMetrics.java:351)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.<clinit>(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:245)
    at mycode.MinimalTest$.entry(MinimalTest.scala:275)
    at mycode.MinimalTest$.main(MinimalTest.scala:248)
    at mycode.MinimalTest.main(MinimalTest.scala)
Caused by: javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: MBean class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin does not implement DynamicMBean, and neither follows the Standard MBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin is not a JMX compliant Standard MBean) nor the MXBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin: Class com.amazonaws.metrics.MetricAdmin is not a JMX compliant MXBean)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Introspector.checkCompliance(Introspector.java:176)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:317)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.registerMBean(MBeans.java:52)
    ... 7 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:531)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:448)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig.<clinit>(InternalConfig.java:43)
    at com.amazonaws.internal.config.InternalConfig$Factory.<clinit>(InternalConfig.java:304)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.userAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:141)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.initializeUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:136)
    at com.amazonaws.util.VersionInfoUtils.getUserAgent(VersionInfoUtils.java:97)
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration.<clinit>(ClientConfiguration.java:60)
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getDefaultConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientConfigurationFactory.getDefaultConfig(AmazonDynamoDBClientConfigurationFactory.java:31)
    at com.amazonaws.ClientConfigurationFactory.getConfig(ClientConfigurationFactory.java:36)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient.<init>(AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient.java:319)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient.<init>(AmazonDynamoDBAsyncClient.java:299)
    at mycode.MinimalTest$.entry(MinimalTest.scala:275)
    at mycode.MinimalTest$.main(MinimalTest.scala:248)
    at mycode.MinimalTest.main(MinimalTest.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig.collectFeatureDefaults(MapperConfig.java:88)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfigBase.<clinit>(MapperConfigBase.java:31)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to instruct ProGuard to keep the MBean classes non-obfuscated to follow the Standard MBean convention. Rules like this might be sufficient:

```
-keep class **MBean {
    void set*(***);
    void set*(int, ***);

    boolean is*(); 
    boolean is*(int);

    *** get*();
    *** get*(int);
}
```

This will instruct ProGuard to keep all classes that have names like *MBean and also keep any getters/setters.